# Orientation change and Notification

Tags: java, android

I want to implement the following scenario:

When a user presses the Home key a Notification is displayed in the Status bar and the App is normally hidden. When user taps the Notification App is normally restored.

Here is my code for this:

```
private int NOTIFICATION = R.string.local_service_started;
private NotificationManager mNM;

private void showNotification() {
    CharSequence text = getText(R.string.local_service_started);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, text, System.currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, JingleCartoucheActivity.class), 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.local_service_label), text, contentIntent);
    mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (!isFinishing()) {
        showNotification();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mNM.cancel(NOTIFICATION);
}
```

All of this is working well except for one thing:

When the App is run and the user rotates the phone, the notification is created and immediately destroyed. Is there a way to detect the phone orientation change in onPause() and not show this Notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current orientation using the `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation`.  At the `onCreate` you store the orientation value and then you can compare it later. Be sure to store the value into a static variable, since when you rotate the phone, the activity is destroyed and so are it's values.

Answer (score 1):

When the user rotate the screen the activity is destroyed and recreated , If you want to display the notification after orientation change make a static flag in onDestroy method and check it in the onCreate method to display the notification like

```
public void onDestroy() {
Flag = 1;
}
```

and

```
public static int Flag = 0;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(Flag == 1) {
    showNotification();
    }
    else {
    .......//
    }
}
```